# How can I trigger javascript function once I load the webpage (Not using form and submit button)

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, onload

For example, i want my HTML page can be able to call a javascript function automatically once it is loaded or refreshed. I don't want to trigger the function by using a form and submit button.

How can I do so? And what is the coding? Many thanks.

**[Edited] Okay it is working right now. Many thanks to all you guys and now I have one more question. Actually I am using servlet to print out the HTML tag to make a HTML page. I am using servlet since i want to load some data from Mysql database and then pass it as parameter to the javascript to carry out some calucation. 
So my last question is How can I control the time of calling javascript? I want to call read database first and triggering the javascript function (at the same time passing the data read as parameter) .How can I do that? Really thanks for your answer!**

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">window.onload=someFunction;</script>` or `<body onLoad="someFunction()">`

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript Call Function After Page Load

```
<body onload="myFunc() ;">
```

or

```
<script>
window.onload=myFunc ;
</script>
```

refer http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/javascript-call-funtion-after-page-load/

Comment: [Edited] Okay it is working right now. Many thanks to all you guys and now I have one more question. Actually I am using servlet to print out the HTML tag to make a HTML page. I am using servlet since i want to load some data from Mysql database and then pass it as parameter to the javascript to carry out some calucation. So my last question is How can I control the time of calling javascript? I want to call read database first and triggering the javascript function (at the same time passing the data read as parameter) .How can I do that? Really thanks for your answer!

Comment: thats another question and comments is very small to answer your question write new answer for this with proper description.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body onload="myfunction();" />
```

Comment: [Edited] Okay it is working right now. Many thanks to all you guys and now I have one more question. Actually I am using servlet to print out the HTML tag to make a HTML page. I am using servlet since i want to load some data from Mysql database and then pass it as parameter to the javascript to carry out some calucation. So my last question is How can I control the time of calling javascript? I want to call read database first and triggering the javascript function (at the same time passing the data read as parameter) .How can I do that? Really thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The browser fires an onload event when the page is loaded. You can attach it like this -

```
<body onload="readyFunction()">
My page
<script>
function readyFunction(){
//your js function
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You've missed your parentheses on your function call, should be - onload="readyFunction()"

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="yourfunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this ?

```
<BODY onLoad="function1()">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onLoad="FunctionName()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery is highly recommended. see here http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put all your javascript here.
});
```

Comment: Can jquery helps me with the second question?(Edited)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
     window.onload = functionName;
</script>
```

or you can just call it as

```
<body>
    ...

    <script>
        functionName();
    </script>
</body>
```

or on body load

```
 <body onload="functionName();">
```

check this link http://grizzlyweb.com/webmaster/javascripts/refresh.asp

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question, if you want to pass data from your jsp to a javascript function, you will have to convert your data into a json string, using libraries like Jackson, or Gson, and put in the string as a variable in your javascript.

SOmething like this -

```
<% String jsonData = getJSONFromObject(dataObject); %> //getJSONFromObject could be a util function which internally uses jackson or gson for conversion
<script>
var jsonStr = "<%= jsonData %>";
var dataObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

</script>
```

YOu can use a JSON lib like https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js for converting the JSON string to an object.